# How to solve this Error on skaffold dev command?

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

```yaml
# skaffold.yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
  kind: Config
  deploy:
    kubectl:
      manifests:
        - infra/k8s/*
  build:
    local:
      push: false
    artifacts:
      - image: subashpoudel7/auth
        context: auth
        docker:
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        sync:
          manual:
            - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
              dest: .
```

Error logs:

```bash
WARN[0000] failed to detect active kubernetes cluster node platform. Specify the correct build platform in the `skaffold.yaml`
file or using the `--platform` flag  subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
     Generating tags...
      - subashpoudel7/auth - subashpoudel7/auth:latest
     Some taggers failed. Rerun with -vdebug for errors.
     Checking cache...
      - subashpoudel7/auth: Found Locally
     Tags used in deployment:
      - subashpoudel7/auth - subashpoudel7/auth:cbf7139bcc21b7690e62334e2776628658fbd1211a7f8f8cdb56aecc6510337f
     Starting deploy...
     Cleaning up...
      - E0716 18:05:37.326541   45936 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get
 "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080:
 connect: connection refused
      - E0716 18:05:37.327159   45936 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get
 "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080:
 connect: connection refused
      - unable to recognize "STDIN": Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080:
 connect: connection refused
      - unable to recognize "STDIN": Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080:
 connect: connection refused
     Cleaning up resources encountered an error, will continue to clean up other resources.
     unable to connect to Kubernetes: getting client config for Kubernetes client: error creating REST client config in-cluster:
 unable to load in-cluster configuration, KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST and
 KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT must be defined
```